# check uncheck all after some checkboxes are clicked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

> HTML

```
<input id='checkall' type='checkbox'/> 
<input class='checka' type='checkbox'/>
<input class='checka' type='checkbox'/>
<input class='checka' type='checkbox'/>
<input class='checka' type='checkbox'/>
```

> Javascript

```
$('#checkall').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('.checka').attr('checked', true);
    }
    else{
        $('.checka').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

After loading the page this works fine.

But if some of the `checka` is checked/unchecked before `checkall` click - it works only on `non-clicked` `checka`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.prop` instead of `.attr`

As the suggestion of Roko, you can use `$('.checka').prop('checked', this.checked);` instead of `if`/`else`

---

`this.checked` returns true if the `#checkall` is checked. Otherwise, it returns false.

So when you say `$('.checka').prop('checked', this.checked);`, you are assigning all the checkboxes with class `.checka` the value of true if `#checkall` is checked and false if it is not.

---

```js
$(function() {
  $('#checkall').change(function() {
    $('.checka').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='checkall' type='checkbox'> Check All
<br />
<input class='checka' type='checkbox'>
<input class='checka' type='checkbox'>
<input class='checka' type='checkbox'>
<input class='checka' type='checkbox'>
```

**Suggestion:**

You might wanna also add

```
$( '.checka' ).change(function(){
    if ( $('.checka:checked').length != $('.checka').length ) $('#checkall').prop('checked', false);
    else $('#checkall').prop('checked', true);
});
```

This will check the *Check All* if all of the other checkboxes are checked.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#checkall').change(function() {
    $('.checka').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });

  $('.checka').change(function() {
    if ($('.checka:checked').length != $('.checka').length) $('#checkall').prop('checked', false);
    else $('#checkall').prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='checkall' type='checkbox'> Check All
<br />
<input class='checka' type='checkbox'>
<input class='checka' type='checkbox'>
<input class='checka' type='checkbox'>
<input class='checka' type='checkbox'>
```

Comment: Since you're already suggesting, use `$('.checka').prop('checked', this.checked);` instead of the if - else